# Is it possible to search a txt-file by words from list and return the line above?

Tags: python, list

I have a txt-file with sentances and am able to find words from a list within it. I would like to print the line above the 'found-line' to a seperate list. I tried it with the below-code, but this only returns `[]`.

Here is my code:

```
fname_in = "test.txt"
lv_pos = []
search_list = ['word1', 'word2']

with open (fname_in, 'r') as f:
    file_l1 = [line.split('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    counter = 0

    for word in search_list:
        if word in file_l1:
            l_pos.append(file_l1[counter - 1])

    counter += 1

print(l_pos)
```

The text file looks somthing like this:

```
Bla bla bla
I want this line1.
I found this line with word1.
Bla bla bla
I want this line2.
I found this line with word2.
```

The result I want this:

```
l_pos = ['I want this line1.','I want this line2.']
```

Comment: `file_l1 = f.readlines()` should be enough. Then instead of `if word ...` you need an inner for loop to iterate over all items (lines) of `file_l1` to check if `word` is contained. Use `enumerate` to find out line number.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of your example you wrote `lv_pos` instead of `l_pos`. Inside the `with` statement you could fix it like this I think:

```
fname_in = "test.txt"
l_pos = []
search_list = ['word1', 'word2']

file_l1 = f.readlines()

for line in range(len(file_l1)):
    for word in search_words:
        if word in file_l1[line].split(" "):
            l_pos.append(file_l1[line - 1])

print(l_pos)
```

I'm not thrilled about this solution but I think it would fix your code with minimal modification.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you got some typos in your code—in some places you wrote `l_pos` and in others, `lv_pos`.

The other problem is I don't think you realize that `file_l1` is a list-of-lists, so the `if word in file_l1:` isn't doing what you think. You need to check each `word` against each of these sublists.

Here's some working code based on your own:

```
fname_in = "simple_test.txt"
l_pos = []
search_list = ['word1', 'word2']

with open(fname_in) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        for word in search_list:
            if word in line:
                l_pos.append(lines[i - 1])

print(l_pos)  # -> ['I want this line1.', 'I want this line2.']
```

---

**Update**

Here's another way to do it that doesn't require reading the entire file into memory at once, so doesn't require as much memory:

```
from collections import deque

fname_in = "simple_test.txt"
l_pos = []
search_list = ['word1', 'word2']

with open(fname_in) as file:
    lines = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in file)  # Generator expression.

    try:  # Create and initialize a sliding window.
        sw = deque(next(lines), maxlen=2)
    except StopIteration:  # File with less than 1 line.
        pass

    for line in lines:
        sw.append(line)
        for word in search_list:
            if word in sw[1]:
                l_pos.append(sw[0])

print(l_pos)  # -> ['I want this line1.', 'I want this line2.']
```

Comment: Mady: What should happen when one of the words is found in the very first line of the file (when there is no previous line)?

Answer (score 0):

Treat the file as a collection of pairs of *lines* and *lines-before*:

```
[prev for prev,this in zip(lines, lines[1:]) 
                    if 'word1' in this or 'word2' in this]
#['I want this line1.', 'I want this line2.']
```

This approach can be **extended** to cover any number of words:

```
words = {'word1', 'word2'}
[prev for prev,this in zip(lines,lines[1:]) 
           if any(word in this for word in words)]
#['I want this line1.', 'I want this line2.']
```

**Finally**, if you care about proper words rather than occurrences (as in `"thisisnotword1"`), you should properly tokenize lines with, say, `nltk.word_tokenize()`:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
[prev for prev,this in zip(lines,lines[1:]) 
           if words & set(word_tokenize(this))]
#['I want this line1.', 'I want this line2.']
```